# Wanna connect via Ingress on algocd-tutorial

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, argocd

Currently processing on this tutorial,
https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps/tree/master/guestbook
https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/getting_started/#5-register-a-cluster-to-deploy-apps-to-optional

My short-term milestone is to render guest-book's UI on browser.
I'm trying to connect via Ingress, and it went wrong.

Error message's like this,

```
Status: 502
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
```

I suppose something's wrong around service and pod.

guestbook-ui-svc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: guestbook-ui-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: guestbook-ui
```

**guestbook-ui-ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  labels:
    app: guestbook-ui
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: guestbook-ui-service
              servicePort: 80
```

**guestbook-ui-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: guestbook-ui
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: guestbook-ui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: guestbook-ui
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/heptio-images/ks-guestbook-demo:0.2
        name: guestbook-ui
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I don't know which part I am missing, please lmk any ambiguous part or more detail.
Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `service` instead.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: guestbook-ui-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: guestbook-ui
```

It has `type: NodePort` added to it.

You can check really good example on how to deploy an app, expose it via a service and add an ingress to it. It's available in kubernetes docs [Deploy a hello, world app](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#deploy-a-hello-world-app).

Also if you are having problem understanding the difference between `NodePort`, `ClusterIP` and what `Ingress` is I recommend reading [Kubernetes NodePort vs LoadBalancer vs Ingress? When should I use what?](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0)

Comment: Ahh I completely forgot about NodePort! That worked! Thanks so much!